# Thread VS RabbitMQ Worker resource consumption

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, worker

I am using JAVA `ExecutorService` threads to send amazon emails, this helps me to make concurrent connection with AmazonSES via API and sends mails at lightning speed. So amazon accepts some number of connection in a sec, so for me its 50 requests in a second. So I execute 50 threads in a second and send around 1million emails daily.

This is working pretty good, but now the number of mails is going to be increased. And I don't want to invest more into RAM and processors.

One of my friend suggested me to use RabbitMQ Workers instead of threads, so instead of 50 threads, I ll be having 50 workers which will do that job.

So before changing some code to test the resource management, I just want to know will there be any huge difference in consumption? So currently when I execute my threads, JAVA consumes 20-30% of memory. So if I used workers will it be low or high?

Or is their any alternative option to this?
Here is my thread email sending function:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Destination destination = new Destination().withToAddresses(new String[] { this.TO });
    Content subject = new Content().withData(SUBJECT);
    Content textBody = new Content().withData(BODY);
    Body body = new Body().withHtml(textBody);
    Message message = new Message().withSubject(subject).withBody(body);
    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withSource(FROM).withDestination(destination).withMessage(message);
    Connection connection = new Connection();
    java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String insert = "";
    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to send an email to " + this.TO);

        ctr++;
        client.sendEmail(request);
        insert = "INSERT INTO email_histories (campaign_id,contact_id,group_id,is_opened,mail_sent_at,mail_opened_at,ip_address,created_at,updated_at,is_sent) VALUES (" + this.campaign_id + ", " + this.contact_id + ", " + this.group_id + ", false, '" + sdf.format(dt) + "', null, null, '" + sdf.format(dt) + "', '" + sdf.format(dt) + "', true);";
        connection.insert(insert);
        System.out.println("Email sent! to " + this.TO);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with RabbitMQ, so I'll have to leave that for others to answer.

> Or is their any alternative option to this?

Instead of using one thread per mail, move that code inside a runable. Add a shared `Semaphore` with the number of permits = the number of mails you want to send per second. Take one permit per mail, refill permits every second from another thread (i.e. a separate [`SchedledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or a `Timer`). Then adjust the Executor thread pool size to whatever your server can handle.

Answer (score 0):

From a RabbitMQ perspective there is a small amount of memory and network resource consumed, although pretty constant for each connection.  If you use a pool of worker threads to read off of the RabbitMQ queue or queues it is possible that it will save you some resources because you are not garbage collecting the individual threads.  As far as alternatives are concerned I would use a Thread Pool in any case.  Although perhaps too heavyweight for your use, [Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) has a very good thread pool that I have used in the past.